# Translation of Time Machine times

Tags: phrases

I am foreign student in Sarajevo, and trying to develop a small time machine for software (not a real one, of course). And I need to show users specified place where currently they are.

How can I translate for this specified times? I wrote like these:

- *The Present*, or as second alternative *Now*
- *In the Past*
- *In the Future*

It looks like in my software:

> February 2, Wednesday 2011 (The Present)

or

> January 8, Wednesday 1996 (In the Past)

Are these good enough, or do you have any better advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would simply use *present*, *past* and *future*:

> January 8, Wednesday 1996 (past)
>       February 3, Thursday 2011 (present)
>       January 8, Wednesday 2016 (future)

Note that these words should not be capitalized.

Comment: Why shouldn't I use capitalizing?

Comment: @dino: They are not proper nouns.

Comment: @Dino - because common nouns are not capitalized in English, except when they are the first word in the sentence.